# Use setuptools to install from location

Tags: python, setuptools, pypi

I have a framework for a site that I want to use in multiple projects but I don't want to submit my framework to PyPi. Is there anyway I can tell my setup.py to install the framework from a specific location?

Here is my current setup.py

```
from setuptools import setup

setup(
    name='Website',
    version='0.2.1',
    install_requires=[
        'boto>=2.6',
        'fabric>=1.4',
        'lepl>=5.1',
        'pygeoip>=0.2.4',
        'pylibmc>=1.2.3',
        'pymongo>=2.2',
        'pyyaml>=3.1',
        'requests>=0.12',
        'slimit>=0.7.4',
        'thrift>=0.8.0',
        'tornado>=2.3',
    ],
)
```

Those dependencies are actually all the dependencies for my framework so if I could include it  somehow I could only have the framework listed here.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like all of your requirements are public (on PyPI), and you don't need specific versions of them, just "new enough". In 2016, when you can count on everyone having a recent-ish version of `pip`, there's really nothing to do. If you just `pip install .` from the source directory or `pip install git+https://url/to/package` or similar, it will just pull the latest versions of the dependencies off the net. The fact that your package isn't on PyPI won't stop pip from finding its dependencies there.

Or, if you want to stash them all locally, you can set up a local PyPI index. Although in that case, it probably would be simpler to push your package to that same local index, and install it from there.

If you need anything more complicated, a [requirements file](http://pip.readthedocs.org/en/stable/user_guide/#requirements-files) can take care of that for you.

In particular, if you need to distribute the package to other people in your organization who may not have your team's local index set up, or for some reason you can't set up a local index in the first place, you can put all the necessary information in the requirements file--or, if it's more appropriate, on the command line used to install your package (which even works if you're stuck with `easy_install` or ancient versions of `pip`).

The documentation gives full details, and [this blog post](https://caremad.io/2013/07/setup-vs-requirement/) explains it very nicely, but the short version is this:

- If you have a local PyPI index, provide `--extra-index-url=http://my.server/path/to/my/pypi/`.
- If you've got an HTTP server that you can drop the packages on, and you can enable the "auto index directory contents" option in your server, just provide `--find-links=http://my.server/path/to/my/packages/`.
- If you want to use local files (or SMB/AFP/etc. file sharing), create a trivial HTML file with nothing but links to all local packages, and provide `--find-links=file:///path/to/my/index.html`.

Again, these can go on the command line of a "to install this package, run this" (or a `curl | sh` install script), but usually you just want to put them in a requirements file. If so, make sure to use only one value per option (e.g., if you want to add two extra indexes, add two `--extra-index-url` params) and put each one on its own line.

A requirements file also lets you specify specific versions of each package, so you can be sure people are deploying with the same code you developed and tested with, which is often useful in these kinds of situations.

Comment: @Tommy Well, the question and answer are 3-1/2 years old. If you want to find the updated links and edit the answer, please feel free to do so. If you think the whole answer is so outdated that it should be rewritten (I wouldn't even mention easy_install if I were answering today..:), you can write a new one. (I don't think the OP is coming back, by someone else might find it by searching, as you presumably did, and if your answer is helpful to them, that's great.

Comment: updated link: http://pip.readthedocs.org/en/stable/reference/pip_install/#requirements-file-format

Comment: @Tommy Now that I think about it, I'm not sure the question is relevant anymore. Now that you can count on everyone having pip 5+, "pip install ." or "pip install git+https://url/to/package" should just work with the OP's setup file, and would be better than installing a requirements file and then doing "python setup.py install" on this package. So it probably is better to write a new answer or edit this one dramatically...

Comment: No, this answer is still relevant. If you are in a large company that hosts an internal pypi server, but want people to be able to install your package that includes deps hosted on that server, without them having to know that server exists, you can just put `extra-index-urls` into your package's requirements.txt file. Also please note that not everything is hosted on git.

Comment: @Tommy Sure, but `pip` also knows how to find things by hg, or a URL to a zipfile, or most other ways you would host a package. If it isn't, then you have to download, unarchive, and `pip install .` instead. Anyway, I've edited the answer, still focusing on the OP's case, but hopefully covering all of the alternatives, and no longer out of date. It's definitely not perfect, so if you have any suggestions, I'd love to hear them.

Comment: your edit about the local PyPi index still kind of misses the key point I mentioned. Lots of big companies host one or many internal PyPi repositories. Your package might have dependencies on those servers. However, if another user comes along and wants to install your package, perhaps hosted on the company's source control site, you don't want them to have to know where all your dependencies lie. That is why `--extra-index-url` in your requirements.txt is so useful. All users of your program can pip your package without needing to know these details.

Comment: @Tommy I honestly haven't worked in an organization set up like that. When I've used a local index, everyone has that local index. So, I can try to edit it to handle your case, but I may get it wrong. Let me try...