# Buildout - installing eggs from source

Tags: python, setuptools, buildout

I have a `buildout` that includes three source repositories for python libraries (it's a Django web app with two reusable libraries). Everything works great from a developers perspective, but now I want to build distributions to deploy. So in my buildout.cfg I have:

```
[buildout]
parts =
    django
develop =
    src/lib1
    src/lib2
    src/django_app
eggs =
    lib1
    lib2
    django_app

[django]
recipe = djangorecipe
...
eggs =
    lib1
    lib2
    django_app
    ...
```

How do I tell buildout to package those as eggs and install them in e.g. `eggs/` instead of `develop-eggs/` as links back to the source?

What I'd like to be able to do after the buildout is capture the built eggs of `lib1` and `lib2` and upload them to my local pypi repo. My alternative is to manually run `python setup.py bdist_egg`, but it seems like `buildout` should already know about that.

Answer (score 0):

Grabbing and installing eggs is different from making and hosting them, that's why buildout itself doesn't provide a pypi server or something like that.

So... you yourself have to make proper eggs/releases and place them somewhere buildout can find them.

- I assume your libraries have a `setup.py`? For a good release you need to update the version number and tag your release in svn/hg/bzr/git. (To make this easier and less time consuming, look at [zest.releaser](http://zestreleaser.readthedocs.org/)).
- There are a couple of pypi clones that you can install locally and where you can upload your custom packages. But the simplest solution is to have a directory with releases somewhere and host it with apache or nginx, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/13354463/27401 . Add that URL to your `[buildout]` part as `find-links = http://example.com/my_packages/`. Buildout will now look inside that page (so: make sure to tell apache to list all the files in that directory). Setuptools uses a standard naming scheme (`mypackage-1.2.zip`), that's how it works.
- Only thing left to do is to get your files into that apache/nginx directory on the server. To start with, a simple custom-made script might be enough. For more automation, look at [tags2sdists](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/tags2sdists/1.1). You feed it a directory with source packages and a directory where it can place the packaged releases. You know, you could even run it from within your buildout as `bin/tags2sdists src/ var/packages/`. This creates source packages from all your tags and places them in `var/packages/`. Afterwards copy  them somewhere else.