# Using an extra python package index url with setup.py

Tags: python, pip, packaging, setup.py, pypi

Is there a way to use an extra Python package index (ala `pip --extra-index-url pypi.example.org mypackage`) with `setup.py` so that running `python setup.py install` can find the packages hosted on `pypi.example.org`?

Answer (score 60, accepted):

If you're the package maintainer, and you want to host one or more dependencies for your package somewhere other than PyPi, you can use the [dependency_links](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setuptools.html#new-and-changed-setup-keywords) option of `setuptools` in your distribution's `setup.py` file. This allows you to provide an explicit location where your package can be located.

For example:

```
from setuptools import setup

setup(
    name='somepackage',
    install_requires=[
        'somedep'
    ],
    dependency_links=[
        'https://pypi.example.org/pypi/somedep/'
    ]
    # ...
)
```

If you host your own index server, you'll need to provide links to the pages containing the actual download links for each egg, not the page listing all of the packages (e.g. `https://pypi.example.org/pypi/somedep/`, not `https://pypi.example.org/`)

Comment: Would be more helpful to include location of this setup.py as well.

Comment: How does that handle a `http` index? For instance pip will want `--trusted-host <index-hostname>` for http indexes.

Comment: as far as I know, dependency links have been deprecated, see e.g.: https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/issues/987 and https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/4187

Comment: The link in the answer says that pip now ignored `dependency_links` but does not say what to use instead.

Comment: Did anybody find a replacement for that?

Comment: This is unfortunately not a robust solution and does not utilize benefits of a dependency manager. The `dependency_links` list needs to list **all** of the dependencies, including transitive ones. Example, you have a dependency on `pandas` and need to use a private mirror of the PyPI. Then you not only need to list `pandas`, but also `numpy`, `python-dateutil`, `pytz`

Comment: This does not seem to be working anymore as pypi dropped support fro --process-dependency-links as of v19.0

Comment: See the warning at the top of https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/dependency_management.html#dependencies-that-aren-t-in-pypi

Answer (score 17):

*setuptools* uses *easy_install* under the hood.

It relies on either *setup.cfg* or *~/.pydistutils.cfg* as documented [here](https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/deprecated/easy_install.html#configuration-files).

Extra paths to *packages* can be defined in either of these files with the [find_links](https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/deprecated/easy_install.html#creating-your-own-package-index). You can override the registry url with *index_url* but cannot supply an *extra-index-url*. Example below inspired by the docs:

```
[easy_install]
find_links = http://mypackages.example.com/somedir/
             http://turbogears.org/download/
             http://peak.telecommunity.com/dist/
index-url = https://mypi.example.com
```

Comment: thanks for setup.cfg example, worked quite well, unfortunately easy install is deprecated now: https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/deprecated/easy_install.html

Answer (score 7):

I wanted to post a latest answer to this since both the top answers are obsolete; use of `easy_install` has been deprecated by `setuptools`.

https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/deprecated/easy_install.html

> Easy Install is deprecated. Do not use it. Instead use pip. If you think you need Easy Install, please reach out to the PyPA team (a ticket to pip or setuptools is fine), describing your use-case.

Please use `pip` moving forward. You can do one of the following:

1. provide `--index-url` flag to `pip` command
2. define `index-url` in `pip.conf` file
3. define `PIP_INDEX_URL` environment variable

https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/topics/configuration/

Comment: pip works well during development, but how do I ship a package then? Setuptools bypasses pip, ignores any option like the extra index, and uses the previous easy_install stuff instead.

Comment: If we now have to repeatedly rewrite setup.py as setup.cfg then as pyproject.toml, this is really tedious and time consuming and more and more I need tools to translate from one format to the next, because otherwise I cannot work on anything else than trial and error guesswork to figure out what is the current installation format.

Answer (score 4):

The following worked for me (develop, not install):

```
$ python setup.py develop --index-url https://x.com/n/r/pypi-proxy/simple
```

Where `https://x.com/n/r/pypi-proxy/simple` is a local PyPI repository.

Comment: Not working, and `python setup.py install --help` doesn't have any params relate to `--index-url`

Comment: @NOZUONOHIGH, thanks, I corrected my answer - it was the "develop", not "install", that accepts an index-url flag.

Comment: If you want to add an extra url like `--extra-index-url` in pip use the `--find-links` option with `setup.py` develop: `python setup.py develop --find-links link`

Answer (score 3):

Found solution when using Dockerfile:

```
RUN cd flask-mongoengine-0.9.5 && \
    /bin/echo -e [easy_install]\\nindex-url = https://pypi.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/simple >> setup.cfg && \
    python setup.py install
```

Which `/bin/echo -e [easy_install]\\nindex-url = https://pypi.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/simple` will exists in file `setup.cfg`:

```
[easy_install]
index-url = https://pypi.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/simple
```

Comment: why not include flask-mogoengin-0.9.5/setup.cfg in your source repository? Why create it at docker build time?

Comment: @JasonHarrison  It's not create but append. By doing so, we don't need to ADD/COPY a additional modified `setup.cfg` file when build the docker image, one Dockerfile and everything works!

Comment: As of Aug 2021, 'index-url' should become 'index_url', at least that's the recommendation I'm getting from setuptools  ` UserWarning: Usage of dash-separated 'index-url' will not be supported in future versions. Please use the underscore name 'index_url' instead`

Answer (score -2):

As far as I know, you cant do that.
You need to tell pip this, or by passing a parameter like you mentioned, or by setting this on the user environment.

Check my ~/.pip/pip.conf:

```
[global]
download_cache = ~/.cache/pip
index-url = http://user:pass@localpypiserver.com:80/simple
timeout = 300
```

In this case, my local pypiserver also proxies all packages from pypi.python.org, so I dont need to add a 2nd entry.

Comment: this answer appears to be wrong. see the last paragraph in the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13353869/use-setuptools-to-install-from-location/13354463?noredirect=1#comment58170495_13354463

Answer (score -2):

this worked for me

```
PIP_INDEX_URL=<MY CUSTOM PIP INDEX URL> pip install -e .
```

I use setup.py and setup.cfg

Answer (score -8):

You can include `--extra-index-urls` in a requirements.txt file. See: http://pip.readthedocs.org/en/0.8.3/requirement-format.html

Comment: I don't think this is correct. The question asks specifically about controlling what `setup.py` does (which we can assume uses `setuptools`) and, IIUC `requirements.txt` is only honoured by `pip`

Comment: I ended up ditching the setup.py and using this method.

Comment: setuptools unable to render `--extra-index-urls` in requirements.txt. The only things it expects is a list of strings with deps version details, etc. `requests>=2.19`