# adding --extra-index-url to setup.py setup_requires

Tags: python, setuptools, requirements.txt

I'm building a package with some internal dependency from a local artifactory.

**requirements.txt**

```
--extra-index-url http://someurl/
some_internal_package
```

**setup.py**

```
....
install_reqs = parse_requirements('requirements.txt', session=PipSession())
reqs = [str(ir.req) for ir in install_reqs]
....
setup(
....
install_requires=[reqs],
...
)
```

Any idea how can i add it? is there some pattern for `reqs` instead of list of strings?

Comment: `--extra-index-url` is supported,  from the [docs](https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/reference/pip_wheel.html#cmdoption--extra-index-url)

Comment: Yeah, I've looked into it a moment ago. Removed my comment as it is absolete

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using an extra python package index url with setup.py](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24443583/using-an-extra-python-package-index-url-with-setup-py)