# declaring private dependencies via setup.cfg in a python package

Tags: python-3.x, pip, setuptools, setup.py

Let's say we create a private python package, that depends on another private python hosted in a private enterprise PyPi repository (artifactory).

The setup.cfg looks as follows,

```
[options]
python_requires = >= 3.6, <3.9.0a0
setup_requires =
    setuptools >= 46.4.0
    wheel
install_requires = [
    keyring
    private-pkg1 >= 0.1.0
    private-pkg2 >= 0.1.0
    simple-parsing ]
```

`$HOME/.pip/pip.confg` is configured download the packages from internal PyPi hosted in Artifactory.

```
[global]
index-url = https://artifactory.mycorp.com/artifactory/api/pypi/PyPI/simple/
```

But this doesn't work when `python setup.py egg_info` is executed

- Can setup.cfg depend on wheel packages stored private PyPi?
- What is the correct way to specify additional repository URLs for downloading dependencies?

Comment: egg_info doesn't invoke `install_requires` -- only `setup_requires`

Answer (score 0):

I think the reason `python setup.py` doesn't work because setuptools does not look for the pip configuration.

There is another related answer using pip: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69846951/10411740.

My working solution is as follows:

##### In `setup.cfg`:

```
install_requires =
    mycorp.private_module==1.0.0
```

and execute `pip install . --index-url=<URL of Pypi repository>` in the
For example:

```
pip install . --index-url=https://__token__:<your_personal_token>@gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/<project_id>/packages/pypi/simple
```

For GitLab pypi package registry: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72019535/10411740